# WebSql iOS13 Support Removed, alternative solutions before to migrate

Tags: ios, google-chrome, safari, web-sql, ios13

The new iOS 13 which was released this week no longer supports WebSQL (bot Safari and Chrome). I see that the best solution would be migrate to indexedDB, but I need to use it right away. Since it cannot be downgraded from a Phone, does anybody have any fast solution to the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes the notes do say "not supported", but if you go to: Settings > Safari > Advanced > Experimental Features, there is a setting called ‘Disable Web SQL’ which is turned on so just turn it off, but I would eventually migrate away from it.

Comment: An alternative I am using is SQLjs ( https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/ ) and just using indexedDB for persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Go to settings, click on safari -> advanced -> experimental features

Look for webSQL.

If you're using an iPad do everything I said above but it’s called disable ... SQL.